# Oracle database foreign key constraints

Tags: database, oracle

I am new to oracle and i'm trying to create a foreign key to another table

```
CREATE TYPE Salary_typ AS OBJECT (
    Sal_SlipId NUMBER (11),
    Sal_BankDetails VARCHAR (255),
    Sal_Salary NUMBER (11,2),
    Sal_Month VARCHAR (255),
    Sal_Employee REF Employee_typ
    )
    /
```

this is the type that i created

and this is the table

```
CREATE TABLE Salary OF Salary_typ (
    Primary Key (Sal_SlipId),
    Sal_Employee REFERENCES Employee 
    )
    /
```

I tried executing these but all i get is a garbage value for foreign key

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Oracle, don't try to create tables based on types - nobody does that!

Do this instead:

```
create table salary (
    Sal_SlipId NUMBER (11),
    Sal_BankDetails VARCHAR (255),
    Sal_Salary NUMBER (11,2),
    Sal_Month VARCHAR (255),
    Sal_Employee REFERENCES employees
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to this with a type?